# nginx rewrite for clean urls

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

What I'm trying to accomplish, is to have people who go to:
http://www.example.com/$SEARCH-QUERY/$PAGE-NUMBER to redirect to search.php?query=SEARCH-QUERY&page=PAGE-NUMBER

I just figured out how to install nginx and configure php-fpm, mysql and everything, but now I'm a bit confused over the rewrites. Here's what I have, that doesn't appear to work correctly:

the php script will automatically assume it's the first page if no page query is sent with it, also I had to do two rewrite rules as I couldn't figure out how to implement it on one line so that it can have it with and without the trailing slash.

```
rewrite ^/search/(.*)$ /search.php?query=$1; 
rewrite ^/search/(.*)$/ /search.php?query=$1;
```

and then for items viewed with paged results

```
rewrite ^/search/(.*)/(.*)$ /search.php?query=$1&page=$2;
rewrite ^/search/(.*)/(.*)$/ /search.php?query=$1&page=$2;
```

If anyone could please help, I'd appreciate it greatly!

Answer (score 3):

You have a basic error in your regexes.

`^/search/(.*)$/` will never match, because `$` means "end of string".  You cannot have `/` after the end of string.

If you need optional `/`, there is a `?` modifier in regexes.

So, try `/search/(.*)/?$`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, your first regex `^/search/(.*)/?$` will match *all* requests starting with `/search/`: it will push a page number into the search string, and also because `*` includes the empty string, it will match null search strings. If the second regex `^/search/(.*)/(.*)/?$` comes later, it will never get matched. If you want to capture the string up to the first slash, use `^/search/([^/]+)/?$` and `^/search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$` (so the wildcards match strings of characters not including `/` instead of strings of all characters, and the `+` matches one-or-more instead of any-number).